# List of Record type matching issue Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to check if a workspace is not available in `all_workspace` table then create new workspace. 
My requirement is if `p_workspace` is not matching the list of value of `v_workspace` then it should create new one.

```
DECLARE
p_workspace VARCHAR2(100):='WS-38515';
TYPE t_ws IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
v_workspace t_ws := t_ws();
Begin
  execute immediate '
    SELECT
    DISTINCT WORKSPACE 
    FROM WMSYS.all_workspaces 
    '
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_workspace;
      FOR i IN v_workspace.first..v_workspace.last LOOP
        IF v_workspace(i) <> p_workspace THEN
           dbms_wm.CreateWorkspace(p_workspace,isrefreshed=>TRUE);
        END IF;
      END LOOP;   
        EXCEPTION
          when others then
            Dbms_Output.put_line(p_workspace || ': ' || SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

It gives me error after creation.

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

WS-38515: ORA-20023: a workspace already exists with the name: 'WS-38515'
```

If I run that workspace individually then its working. but when I am passing through block with checking availability then its not working.

```
execute dbms_wm.CreateWorkspace('WS-38515',isrefreshed=>TRUE);
```

Please help anyone.

Comment: Given that you are hard-coding the name of the workspace you want to create, I fail to see the utility of such a procedure.  Now if you were to pass that as in input parameter, perhaps.  But even with that, how often do you create a new workspace?  All this trouble of writing a procedure that, when it comes down to it, issues a single command . . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason that you need dynamic SQL, a collection, and a loop to iterate over the collection?  It sounds like you just want to check whether the row exists which can be done with a simple `count` (you could make the check more efficient by writing it as a `where exists` but that's probably not important here)

```
declare
  p_workspace VARCHAR2(100):='WS-38515';
  l_num_workspaces integer;
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_num_workspaces
    from WMSYS.all_workspaces 
   where workspace = p_workspace;

  if( l_num_workspaces = 0 )
  then 
    dbms_wm.CreateWorkspace(p_workspace,isrefreshed=>TRUE);
  end if;
end;
```

Of course, you could also just skip the check, call `CreateWorkspace`, and handle the exception when it already exists.  If you expect that the vast majority of the time you're going to create the workspace, that might be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create the workspace at every iteration of the loop and not checking all the items in the loop and, only after not finding it in all items, then creating it. To fix your code, it should be:

```sql
DECLARE
  p_workspace VARCHAR2(100):='WS-38515';
  TYPE t_ws IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
  v_workspace t_ws;
  p_not_found BOOLEAN := TRUE;
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT WORKSPACE 
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_workspace;
  FROM WMSYS.all_workspaces 

  FOR i IN v_workspace.first..v_workspace.last LOOP
    IF v_workspace(i) <> p_workspace THEN
      p_not_found := FALSE;
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;   

  IF p_not_found THEN
     dbms_wm.CreateWorkspace(p_workspace,isrefreshed=>TRUE);
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  when others then
    Dbms_Output.put_line(p_workspace || ': ' || SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

However, your code could simply be to try to create the workspace and catch the exception:

```
DECLARE
  workspace_exists EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( workspace_exists, -20023 );
  p_workspace WMSYS.all_workspaces.workspace%TYPE := 'WS-38515';
BEGIN
  DBMS_WM.CreateWorkspace( p_workspace,isrefreshed=>TRUE);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN workspace_exists THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( p_workspace || ': ' || SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

Or, if `DBMS_WM.CreateWorkspace` is an expensive operation then:

```sql
DECLARE
  p_workspace WMSYS.all_workspaces.workspace%TYPE := 'WS-38515';
  p_found     WMSYS.all_workspaces.workspace%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT WORKSPACE
  INTO   p_found;
  FROM   WMSYS.all_workspaces
  WHERE  workspace = p_workspace
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( p_workspace || ': Already Exists' );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_WM.CreateWorkspace( p_workspace,isrefreshed=>TRUE);
END;
/
```

Comment: thanks, but someone already answered before..... but thanks for your suggestion too :-)